# why does nested loop start from 0 and how to change it to start from where it had left?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datatable

I want to generate a code that will write 20 rows from each of two different dataframes. Therefore, I created something like below. Everything works fine except nested loop (u) starts from 0 each time. Can you help me how to fix it to start from where it left, please?

```
 for t, row in results_table1.iterrows():
    f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in row.values]) + " \\\\\n")
    if t > 0 and t % 20 == 0:
        for u, row in results_table2.iterrows():
            f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in row.values]) + " \\\\\n")
            if u > 0 and u % 20 == 0:
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to alternate between the two tables? Then I would just access the content by index:

```
for t in range(20):
    f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in results_table1.iloc[t].values]) + " \\\\\n")
    f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in results_table2.iloc[t].values]) + " \\\\\n")
```

Edit:
to get line 0-19 from table 1, then 0-19 from table 2, then 20-39 from table one etc:

(based on the [answer of im_vutu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72182435/7438122) but making sure all lines are copied, even if the total is not divisible by 20)

```
u = 0
for t, row in results_table1.iterrows():
    f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in row.values]) + " \\\\\n")
    if t > 0 and t % 20 == 0 or t == len(results_table1.index)-1:
        for i in range(0,20):
            try:
                f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in results_table2.iloc[u]]) + " \\\\\n")
                u += 1
            except KeyError:
                break
```

Comment: no, I would like to write 20 from results_table1 and then 20 from results_table2 and then 20:40 from results_table1 and next 20: from results_table2...

Comment: Understood. What would you like to do if table1 is much larger than table 2? Stop after last row of table 2 or continue writing lines only of table 1? Or are they guaranteed to always be of same length?

Comment: yes, they are going to be the same length. I just want to divide the very wide table into two and present them within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize u outside of your loop increment u and use as index to the second dataframe.

```
u = 0
for t, row in results_table1.iterrows():
    f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in row.values]) + " \\\\\n")
    if t > 0 and t % 20 == 0:
            for i in range(0,20):
                try:
                        f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in results_table2.iloc[u]]) + " \\\\\n")
                        u += 1
                except:
                        pass
f.close()
```